# Connecting the Fibres of a Lefschetz Fibration With Disconnected Fibres.

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, symplectic-geometry, 4-manifolds

The following is an exercise set by Chris Wendl in his book *Holomorphic Curves in Low Dimensions*. I'm fairly new to the subject, and wasn't sure how to approach it, so any help with it would be appreciated.

> Let $M$ be a smooth, closed, connected, oriented $4$-manifold and $\pi:M\rightarrow \Sigma$ a Lefschetz fibration onto a smooth, closed, connected, oriented $2$-manifold $\Sigma$. Assume that $\pi$ has disconnected fibres. Show that there exists a finite covering $\varphi:\Sigma'\rightarrow \Sigma$ of degree at least $2$, and a factorisation $\pi=\varphi\circ\pi'$, where $\pi':M\rightarrow\Sigma'$ is a Lefschetz fibration with connected fibres.

For completeness we recall that a *Lefschetz fibration* is a map $\pi$, as in the exercise, with finitely many critical points, such that around each critical point $p$ there exist complex coordinates $(z_1,z_2)$ on $M$ for which $\pi$ has the local form $(z_1,z_2)\mapsto z_1^2+z_2^2$ for some complex chart on $\Sigma $ at $\pi(p)$. Both charts are assumed to be compatible with the orientations on each respective manifold.

Comment: I am not familiar with this field, but here is a thought: for $p\in\Sigma$, define the fiber $\varphi^{-1}(p)$ to be the set of connected components in $\pi^{-1}(p)$.

Comment: @AmitaiYuval, thanks for the comment. Your idea seems fruitful, and maybe it is the correct path, but there seem to be some technical difficulties. I'm not sure how to define the map $\pi'$. Also the presence of singular fibres seems to complicate the picture substantially.

Comment: So I would define $\pi'$ by mapping a point $q\in M$ to its connected component in the fiber $\pi^{-1}(\pi(q))$. And yes, I guess handling the singularities is the most interesting part here.